# coproduct of the homology of iterated loop space on spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, loop-spaces, configuration-spaces

Let $\Omega^{n+1}S^{n+1}$ be the base-pointed $(n+1)$-iterated loop space on the $(n+1)$-sphere. In the paper [The homology of $\mathcal{C}_{n+1}$-spaces, $n\geq 0$, F. Cohen, Lecture notes in mathematics Vol. 533,](http://www3.nd.edu/~taylor/papers/cocs.pdf) page 226, Theorem 3.2, it is proved that as a $AR_n\Lambda_n$-Hopf algebra,
$$
H_*(\Omega^{n+1}S^{n+1};\mathbb{Z}_p)\cong GW_n H_*(S^0;\mathbb{Z}_p)
$$
for primes $p\geq 2$.

**Question:** In page 223, it is said that "the coproduct are determined by the diagonal Cartan formulas (page 213, (4))". I do not understand how to write the coproduct of $H_*(\Omega^{n+1}S^{n+1};\mathbb{Z}_p)$ explicitly?

In the paper [On the homology of configuration spaces,](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/homo_iter.pdf) Section 4, as an associative and commutative $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra, a generator set of $H_*(\Omega^{n+1}S^{n+1};\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is given. I want to know how to obtain the coproduct formulas of $H_*(\Omega^{n+1}S^{n+1};\mathbb{Z}_p)$ as a coalgebra.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------==========================================================================

For the answer below, I have a question.

In the paper [On the homology of configuration spaces](http://www3.nd.edu/~taylor/papers/cocs.pdf), Section 4.1, a basis for the graded vector space $H_*(\Omega^m S^m;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is given as

$(*)$
$$
u_0, u_1, Q_I u_0, Q_I u_1
$$
where $0,1$ denote the two generators of $H_0(S^0;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ and $Q_I=Q_{i_1}Q_{i_2}\cdots Q_{i_r}$ for $I=(i_1,i_2,\cdots, i_r)$,  $0<i_1\leq i_2\leq \cdots\leq i_r<m$.

By the Cartan formula (cf. [The homology of $\mathcal{C}_{n+1}$-spaces, $n\geq 0$, F. Cohen](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/homo_iter.pdf), page 213)
[image]

In the answer below, we calculated that

$(**)$
$$\Delta_* Q_I u_0=\sum_{t_1=0}^{i_1}\sum_{t_2=0}^{i_2}\cdots \sum _{t_r=0}^{i_r}Q_{t_1}Q_{t_2}\cdots Q_{t_r}u_0\otimes Q_{i_1-t_1}Q_{i_2-t_2}\cdots Q_{i_r-t_r}u_0,
$$

$(***)$
$$\Delta_* Q_I u_1=\sum_{t_1=0}^{i_1}\sum_{t_2=0}^{i_2}\cdots \sum _{t_r=0}^{i_r}Q_{t_1}Q_{t_2}\cdots Q_{t_r}u_1\otimes Q_{i_1-t_1}Q_{i_2-t_2}\cdots Q_{i_r-t_r}u_1.
$$

Is this result correct or wrong?

**Question:** The problem is that $Q_{t_1}Q_{t_2}\cdots Q_{t_r}u_0$, $Q_{i_1-t_1}Q_{i_2-t_2}\cdots Q_{i_r-t_r}u_0$, $Q_{t_1}Q_{t_2}\cdots Q_{t_r}u_1$, $Q_{i_1-t_1}Q_{i_2-t_2}\cdots Q_{i_r-t_r}u_1$ are not included in the basis. It does not make sense. Why?

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

I find the Adem relations for $p=2$
[image]
[image]

i.e.

for $t_1>2t_2$,

$$
Q_{t_1}Q_{t_2}=\sum_{t_1/2 \leq i\leq t_1-t_2-1}(-1)^{t_1+i}(2i-t_1,t_1-t_2-i-1)Q^{t_1+t_2-i}Q^i.
$$

How to apply the Adem relation to simplify equations $(**)$, $(***)$ to sums of tensor products of basis given in $(*)$?

Comment: Commented on an identical question: you have to use the Adem relations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case for odd primes being slightly more complicated to write down due to the Bockstein, we deal with the case $p=2$ here, although the odd prime cases work essentially in the same way.  Since it is a Hopf algebra, we have
$$\Delta (x\cdot y) =\Delta (x)\cdot \Delta (y).$$
Thus it suffices to know the coproduct on algebra generators.  However, the algebra generators are of the form $Q^{I_1}Q^{I_2}\cdots Q^{I_r}([1])$, and $[-1]$.  The coproduct on $[\pm1]$ is given by $\Delta ([\pm 1])=[\pm 1]\otimes [\pm 1]$, and the repeated use of Cartan formula gives
$$\Delta (Q^{I_1}Q^{I_2}\cdots Q^{I_r}([1]))=\Sigma _{J_1,J_2,\ldots J_r}
Q^{J_1}Q^{J_2}\cdots Q^{J_r}([1])\otimes Q^{I_1-J_1}Q^{I_2-J_2}\cdots Q^{I_r-J_r}([1]).$$

Comment: Thanks! Does $[-1]$ mean the base point of $S^0$? Why the $Q^I$'s do not act both on $[1]$ and $[-1]$, but only act on $[1]$?

Comment: Are the algebra generators of the form $Q^{I_1}Q^{I_2}\cdots Q^{I_r}([1])$ and $Q^{I_1}Q^{I_2}\cdots Q^{I_r}([-1])$, instead of $Q^{I_1}Q^{I_2}\cdots Q^{I_r}([1])$ and $[-1]$?

Comment: See www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/homo_iter.pdf chapter 4.  The base point of $S^0$ is [0].  [-1] is the component of the degree -1 map.